# Finding the unknown variable

Tags: transcendental-equations, real-numbers

What is the value of $x$ in $x^{x}=25$? How can this be solved in the easiest way of all? I just couldn't deduce any idea regarding where to start.

Comment: Do you know about the Product-log-Function?

Comment: The product-log function (it's called that in Mathematica), is more commonly called the [Lambert W function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function).

Answer (score 2):

$$
\begin{align}
x^x&=25\tag{1}\\
x\log(x)&=\log(25)\tag{2}\\
\log(x)e^{\log(x)}&=\log(25)\tag{3}\\
\log(x)&=\mathrm{W}(\log(25))\tag{4}\\
x&=e^{\mathrm{W}(\log(25))}\tag{5}\\
&=\frac{\log(25)}{\mathrm{W}(\log(25))}\tag{6}
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$(2)$: take log of both sides
$(3)$: $x=e^{\log(x)}$
$(4)$: if $we^w=x$, then $w=\mathrm{W}(x)$, $\mathrm{W}$ is [Lambert W](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function)
$(5)$: exponentiate $(4)$
$(6)$: divide $(2)$ by $(4)$

Answer (score 0):

The solution of
$
x^x=a
$
is
$$
x = \frac{\log a}{W(\log a)}
$$
where $W$ is the [Lambert W function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function), not an elementary function.

Answer (score -4):

\begin{align}
x^x &= 25 \\  
x^2 &= 25
\end{align}
possibilities, $x=5$ or $x=-5$ because $5^2 = 25$ and $-5^2 =25$
description:
\begin{align}
-5\times-5  
&=(-1)\times5\times(-1)\times5 \\
&=(-1)\times(-1)\times5\times5 \\
&=1\times5\times5 \\
&=25
\end{align}

Comment: Usually $x^x\ne x^2$.